# Making focus works inside a CK Editor 5 createUIElement

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

So I've a custom widget which renders a custom component.

```
conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToElement({
    model: 'modelName',
    view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
      const modelName = modelElement.getAttribute('modelName');
      const modelNameView = viewWriter.createContainerElement('span', {
        class: 'modelName',
        'data-modelName': modelName,
      });

      const reactWrapper = viewWriter.createUIElement(
        'span',
        {
          class: 'modelName__react-wrapper',
        },
        function (this, domDocument) {
          const domElement = this.toDomElement(domDocument);

          rendermodelName(modelName, domElement);

          return domElement;
        },
      );

      viewWriter.insert(
        viewWriter.createPositionAt(modelNameView, 0),
        reactWrapper,
      );

      return toWidgetEditable(modelNameView, viewWriter);
    },
  });
```

Where `rendermodelName` will give back a React component with a simple input box as

```
return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  );
```

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html.

But the problem is, whenever I tried to add some content inside the input, the focus is lost from the field and automatically moved to the surrounding editor. What am I missing. Tried creating a focushandler and adding the `modelNameView` to it.

Should I go with the new `createRawElement`? My current CK5 is 20.0.0 So I don't want any breaking changes coming now.

EDIT:
I researched a little bit more. seems like `createRawElement` may not work here. I think this doesn't have a simple solution. I tried with `allowContentOf: '$block'` which also not letting me focus. But these values are explicitly for normal CK widget, not for a react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by adding this tag to the parent div that wraps my Vue component.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/widget-internals.html#exclude-dom-events-from-default-handlers

Adding from CKE Docs:

Sometimes it can be useful to prevent processing of events by default handlers, for example using React component inside an UIElement in the widget where, by default, widget itself wants to control everything. To make it possible the only thing to do is to add a data-cke-ignore-events attribute to an element or to its ancestor and then all events triggered by any of children from that element will be ignored in default handlers.

Let’s see it in an short example:

```
<div data-cke-ignore-events="true">
    <button>Click!</button>
</div>
```

In the above template events dispatched from the button, which is placed inside  containing `data-cke-ignore-events` attribute, will be ignored by default event handlers.

Comment: thanks walker. updated your answer with the content. This is the latest way of handling this. When I was asking this question, this was not done. https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/4600#issuecomment-699756927

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue.

CKEditor will takes all the events on React component which you hosted on Widget.

The work around is to stop propagation of events to CKEditor which are fired from your DOM element(`domElement`) where your React component hosted.

Here is the sample code:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/compare/proto/input-widget#diff-44ca1561ce575490eac0d660407d5144R239

You should stop all required events. Also you can't paste any content inside the input field of React component. That will also listened by `clipboardInput` event of CKEditor.

Comment: This works. I think maybe I should catch `clipboardInput` also.

Comment: Giving bounty to this answer. Not expecting more answer on the same as it's been 10 days already.

Comment: Click is not working with this method. Let me know if anyone finds a solution to make click works